# VS2015 / MsBuild / vsvars32.bat : Cannot determine the location of the VS installation

Tags: batch-file, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I use a batch to build my solution. It work fine with Visual Studio 2013.
But with Visual Studio 2015 this error occurs :

> ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS installation

**Batch for VS2013**

> call "%VS120COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"
>      msbuild solution.sln /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU"

Work fine.

**Batch for VS2015**

> call "%VS140COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"
>      msbuild solution.sln /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU"

ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS installation.

---

The environment variable **VS140COMNTOOLS** is defined to

> **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools**

It's not the good path on my OS (Windows 8.1 64 bits).
So I set **VS140COMNTOOLS** to

> **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools**

But error message still the same.

If anyone has ideas...
Thanks in advance :)

## EDIT

I have found this temporary workaround with mklink (and add compatibility for older Visual Studio) :

> ```
> IF NOT "%VS140COMNTOOLS%" == "" (  
>     IF NOT EXIST "%VS140COMNTOOLS%" (  
>         mklink /J "%VS140COMNTOOLS%" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools"  
>     )  
>     call "%VS140COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"  
>     echo Visual Studio 2015...
> ) ELSE (  
>     IF NOT "%VS120COMNTOOLS%" == "" (  
>         call "%VS120COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"  
>        echo Visual Studio 2013...
>     ) ELSE (  
>         call "%VS110COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"  
>         echo Visual Studio 2012...
>     )  
> )
> ```

... and after call msbuild.

Have you a best solution ?...

Comment: This is a broken registry problem, your machine appears to be missing the required registry entry in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7, 14.0 value.  Or the 32-bit version in Wow6432Node, depends on the flavor of cmd.exe.  Very unhealthy of course, feel free to panic.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hans. In my registry I have HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\ and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\. It appears to be correct.

Comment: Hmm, that limits the number of possible explanations.  You'll need to find out why vcvarsqueryregistry.bat in the same directory fails to get its job done.  A massive environment that exceeds the max size is all I can think of.

Answer (score 8):

For me, the path in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7 was missing `(x86)`.

It can be solved with this `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7]
"14.0"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\"
```

*Thank you for you hint.*

Answer (score 4):

I recently had the same issue. Problem was an overly long PATH, resulting in the `C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe` command not being found when called in the batch file. I removed what I could from my `PATH` and this corrected the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this advice, i would try to clean my PATH :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with VS 2013 and %VS110COMNTOOLS%... I tried loads of stuff that I found over the internet but none worked, also the most common solution that I found online was that C:\windows\system32 was missing from the PATH enviroment variable, but on my machine all the variables were correct and pointing to the right directories.

I had a windows 10 image with vs2017 installed and no other visual studios previously installed, so I restored that image, then proceeded to install VS2013, then I installed VS2010 and then finally installed VS2012.

After doing this the builds went fine and the error disappeared... I guess that installing VS2012 as the last one fixed the problem concerning the VS110COMNTOOLS variable, even tho I tried to reinstall all the visual studios before rolling back to the windows 10 image I had.

I hope you can do something similar on your machine,  try to restore your system to a point before the visual studio installations and then install the visual studios you need leaving the VS2015 as the last one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that registry editing was disabled on my PC entirely, by my system administrator.

This resulted in the command line command `reg` being inoperable, and that leads to the reported error.

The solution was to get registry access enabled.

Note - this also caused `regedit` to be disabled so the manual fix noted in another answer was not workable for me.