# TFS: can "tf workfold /cloak" be done with TFPT?

Tags: powershell, command-line, tfs

Microsoft Team Foundation Server appears to have at least two different command line interfaces: TF (which runs in a "Developer Command Prompt", an old-style CMD with some definitions added) and TFPT (TFS power tools, in particular supporting powershell verbs.)

I need to run a series of "tf workfold /cloak" commands, but currently can't get  a "Developer Command Prompt" (cf. [VS2015 / MsBuild / vsvars32.bat : Cannot determine the location of the VS installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31680687/vs2015-msbuild-vsvars32-bat-cannot-determine-the-location-of-the-vs-instal), but I have thus far been unable to solve this.)

Since I know about TFPT (and prefer powershell to cmd anyway) I'd be happy to solve it that way. However TF and TFPT appear to support a very different set of verbs. (Compare for example:

TF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0(v=vs.100).aspx

TFPT (no online manual!? cf. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/db69442c-8cd4-4535-9cd3-9bac7f529387/tfpt-manual-or-users-guide?forum=tfsgeneral)

from which I get the impression that TF is maturer, much more powerful, but deprecated ("This documentation is archived and is not being maintained."))

So my question is: can I do "tf workfold /cloak" with TFPT under powershell?

Answer (score 0):

The `tfpt` doesn't have a command which has the same function like `tf workfold /cloak`. You could run `tfpt /?` to list all tfpt commands.

On the other hand, it also supports that TF command could also be run in "**Command Prompt**" not only "Developer Command Prompt". You could use "Command Prompt" to run 'tf workfold /cloak'.

Comment: Thanks. I've since learned from a colleague that TF handles most of the basics and TFPT adds functionality on top. That partly explains the lack of overlap I found in functions covered. I still wonder whether TF is going away -- only because of the comment I cited about the documentation.

Comment: @Tim No, the TF command is not going away, the link about TF command you posted above is the old version document. For TFS 2015 and TFS 2017, we refer to [this document](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands#run-a-command). And the TFPT command do can't replace the TF command.

Comment: @Tim If your **Developer Command Prompt** doesn't work, you could use   **Command Prompt** to run TF command.